# wordpress not properly functioning anymore after moving it to another domain

Tags: wordpress

I followed the instructions on http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress under 'Moving WordPress to a New Server' and 'If You Want Your Old Blog To Still Work'

So I made a copy of everything marked is as old, then changed the domain under the WP settings, made a new copy. And now put the first copy back but when I go to the login page I can reach it, but it's without the usual markup as first. It's all skinned out. 
After I login, worpress uses the new domain instead of the old domain which the old copy of wordpress used!!
what went wrong??
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out something went wrong with backing up the database, so that's why it wasn't working well. I had to change the url values directly in the database to make it work again.